# Decrease openssl SECLEVEL in conf for only one connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm working on establishing a connection to a database server without encryption, as TLS isn't supported by the database system. Currently, I'm using isql to validate the connection:

```
isql -v -k "Driver={Driver SQL Server};Server=mysql-server;Database=DATABASE;UID=user;PWD=pwd;"
```

However, I encountered an issue with error code `0x2746`, indicating the absence of TLS support. After researching online, it seems that reducing the `SECLEVEL` to 0 in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` resolves the problem:

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

After rebooting, the connection works fine. But setting the `SECLEVEL` to 0 system-wide isn't ideal for obvious reasons. Instead, I'd prefer a per-connection configuration. So, I attempted the following:

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2

[mysql-server]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

However, this produces the same error as mentioned at the beginning of this post.
Any insights or suggestions on achieving per-connection configuration without compromising system security would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the system OpenSSL config file and make your changes to the SECLEVEL in the copy.

When running your application that needs to use the amended config file set the `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to point at your new config file.

e.g.

```
cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf myconf.cnf
# Edit myconf.cnf as appropriate
OPENSSL_CONF=myconf.cnf isql -v -k "Driver={Driver SQL Server};Server=mysql-server;Database=DATABASE;UID=user;PWD=pwd;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea! So basically this works just fine with isql. However, what I did not mentioned is that my application layer is R. So i tried setting the conf in R via Sys.setenv("OPENSSL_CONF" = "myconf.cnf") which seems not to work.

Do you have any other idea than creating a separate file for it? From R I configured the connection via the odbc.ini file.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.